# Missing features for classifier

Tags: machine-learning, parameter

If I am given 60 features along with test label and I was to find values of other features what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: What are the _other features_, and why do you want to find their values?

Answer (score 1):

A good answer to this question has to rely on the specific dataset / domain.

The questions I would ask myself are (in this order):

- Can I solve my classification task without those features? → Just remove those features
- Do I know of a relationship between features I know and the (partially) missing feature? → Find hard rules to fill those missing ones
- Otherwise: Train a classifier / regression model to fill those missing features